# My screen has turned violet and I can't login

Tags: login, freeze, remote-login

Suddenly my ubuntu machine changed its login page and it is now violet asking me for my password. However there is no response to my keyboard or mouse.
The PC is stuck
I can login remotely from another computer.
What can I do to unfreeze it?

I have done

> ps
> PID TTY          TIME CMD
> 506918 pts/22   00:00:00 bash
> 507139 pts/22   00:00:00 ps

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
First I used [top](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-check-running-process-in-ubuntu-linux-using-command-line/) to see what was happening.
Then I saw the isolated web occupying it so I killed firefox
still xorg occupied it then I found this [article](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/high-cpu-usage-on-xorg-when-the-external-monitor-is-plugged-in/169173) so I disconnected my external monitor and I could login